# Angular 9 unit test Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngrx

I am writing unit test case and trying to spy a service function but got stuck with converting array to observable i tried similar question on stack-overflow but nothing worked. Please help how do i call service function

I am working on latest version of angular and ngrx

Options i tried

1)

```js
spyOn(service, 'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(data));
```

2) This one didn't covered subscribe part in unit test component

```js
spyOn(service, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(data));
```

whole code: testcase never enter subscribe part of this.dataService.getState()

```js
// component:

getState(){
    this.dataService.getState().subscribe(s => s.forEach(element => {
      this.data.push(element.name);
    }));
}
  
//test case

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.inject(DataService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
it('should call get data Function', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(data));
  });
```

Comment: You're probably using an old import location with an updated package. What version of `rxjs`?

Comment: "rxjs": "~6.5.4"

Comment: import { Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

Comment: I did this in beforeEach .... service = TestBed.inject(DataService);

Comment: That looks right. Please edit the TestBed configuration, the `beforeEach` method where you do the spying and the method where the spied method is called in the unit under test into your post.

Comment: Is `getState` called from `ngOnInit`?

Comment: I have updated code. Please check

Comment: yes getState is called from ngOnInit

Comment: The problem is `ngOnInit` runs before you setup the spy. You can move the `detectChanges` call into each test spec after setting up the spy (if you need different returns from the mock) or setup the spy in the `beforeEach` (if you always want the same return for all specs).

Comment: I have added state = spyOn(service, 'getState'); in beforeEach. but still no luck. Please helpme if you have any link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup a test, the component instantiates when you call `fixture.detectChanges`. Since instantiation invokes lifecycle hooks, any code in the `ngOnInit` function executes before your first test spec.

If `data` is a constant, do:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.get(DataService);
    spyOn(service, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(data));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

If `data` is a variable, do:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.get(DataService);
  });
```

// test method

```
it('should call get data Function', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(data));
    // other required setup
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // test stuff
  });
```

Comment: if i call fixture.detectChanges() in both beforeEach and it. what will happen?

Comment: Each call to `detectChanges` runs the change detection cycle. The first call also instantiates the component because you can't have a change detection cycle without one.

Answer (score 0):

You're running `fixture.detectChanges()` inside you're `beforeEach` is the issue.
The moment you call `detectChanges` your component gets initialized, so modify the code as below

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.inject(DataService);

  });

it('should call get data Function', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(data));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: Calling `detectChanges` in `beforeEach` isn't wrong. It's just not always what you want.

Comment: My bad I didn't mean that to be wrong, but that's the issue

Comment: We agree on that!